# Power Grid China/Korea strategy - is it any different from the base game?

Tags: power-grid

I just got Power Grid China/Korea and was wondering if there was anything (besides for the two markets on the Korea side of the board) I should look for strategy-wise that is different from the base game.

Comment: *Anything*??? The restriction to, for a given player, one market (north or south) in a round is pretty glaring.

Comment: I know that, I was just asking if there were any tips as to when to use the resource market for the north or south, and anything else like that, sorry if it seemed like a dumb question :/

Comment: I think it's less a question of *when to use which market*, and more a question of *given the split markets and what power plants the players currently own (including me!), which plant should I bid on*?

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Are there any other tips you have for me going into the China side of the board, and any other tips for the Korea side, then?

Comment: Sorry - it's been so long, and I've only played each side once!

Answer (score 1):

At a high level the strategy is the same.  Obviously the difference in connection costs between cities and the different resource refresh rates will create strategic differences, but this is fairly complex and nuanced and so beyond the scope of an answer.

As far as the rules differences, the changes to what you want to do are more tactical (what you do this move) than strategic (how you plan the game).  The more strategic changes are as follows:

For Korea, you don't want to combine coal and nuclear as the North has no nukes (ironic) but has the cheaper coal.  Garbage plants are also more competitive on Korea, so take that into account when planning your power plant build.

For China, since the power plants come out in order, there aren't going to be windfall opportunities (a plant that powers 5 cities won't be available until you get to that part of the deck).  Here, you pretty much want to upgrade your plants only when you need to get more capacity rather than opportunistically (when there is a plant that looks good), as there is always going to be a better plant coming up next.